# magento 2column-right template where doe s $this refer too?

Tags: templates, magento, this, php

in the template.phtml file there is a line of code which refers to the content, using 
getChildHtml('content') ?>
which echos out the content and the containing divs, i wish to access this raw code so i can insert
some custom data but for the life of me cannot find where it is?! i have found the Mage_Page_Block_Html class in the core but cannot see any html that it is throwing out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't mean to insult so I apologise in advance. That is a really newbie question. You might do well to read some [guides](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base) first.

Answer (score 1):

In the Admin, if you go to System>Config>Advanced>Developer and select your Store View from the Scope Selector (top-left), you can turn on Template and Block hints.  That will tell you exactly which PHP Block is generating the code and therefore `$this` relates to.

Generally, all the basic layout templates are backed by `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, and all blocks inherit from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`.

Cheers,
Jonathan

Comment: Hi and thankyou, where would the Mage_Core_Block_Abstract be found roughly?

Comment: The class name translates into it's location. So Mage_Core_Block_Abstract becomes 'app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php'

Answer (score 1):

As always, I recommend [understanding what the entire layout system is doing](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) to understand what's going on.

As to your specific question, `$this` always refers to the template's Block class.  (Every phtml template has a Block class in Magento).  Which class this is will depend on what's in your layout XML files.  You can always output the class at runtime with something like this

var_dump(get_class($this));

The `getChildHtml` method is defined on the base abstract block class

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php

This method is used by ALL blocks, so be sure you take this into account with your code.

Answer (score 0):

as a side note.. if you ever wondering where a $this is point to you can also use

```
echo get_class($this)
```

helped me out quiet a few times